# matlab plots are nothing but narrow lines

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot

I'm trying to plot a couple of spectrograms and I can't seem to force matlab to plot them properly. They only appear as lines like in this [image: one]

I don't understand what the problem is with this, and why it randomly does this, and sometimes it is just happy with everything and other times it can't anything.

```
figure(1);
set(gcf, 'Visible', 'off');
subplot(6,1,1);
spectrogram(Chan1, Window, overLap,windowSize, sampleFreq, 'yaxis');
colorbar;
axis([0 maxTime 0 75000]);
title('North-South');


subplot(6,1,2);
spectrogram(Chan2, Window, overLap,windowSize, sampleFreq, 'yaxis');
colorbar;
axis([0 timeSerries(end) 0 75000]);
title({'','East-West'});

subplot(6,1,3);
spectrogram(Chan1, Window, overLap,windowSize, sampleFreq, 'yaxis');
colorbar;
axis([0 maxTime 0 10000]);
title({'','North-South'});


subplot(6,1,4);
spectrogram(Chan2, Window, overLap,windowSize, sampleFreq, 'yaxis');
colorbar;
axis([0 timeSerries(end) 0 10000]);
title({'','East-West'});

subplot(6,1,5);
plot(timeSerries, Chan1);
title({'','Noth-Sout',});
axis([0 timeSerries(end) -5000 5000]);

subplot(6,1,6);
plot(timeSerries, Chan2);
title({'','East-West'})
axis([0 timeSerries(end) -5000 5000]);

%Save said plots
saveas(1,summaryPlotName);


clf;
%close('all', hidden);
close('all');
```

I'm fairly new to matlab, so I might be missing something obvious or fundamental. I have tried plotting the spectrogram as found in spectrogram documentation as well as imsec, but they just make matters worse.

EDIT: I have cleared the workspace, restarted matlab, and restarted my computer all to no avail.

Comment: Does it look better onscreen if you resize your figure window? To 'fix' the saved image from `saveas` you might have to adjust the `PaperSize` property of your figure. Because `subplot` spaces the axes equally it may just be too much to cram in a small area.

Comment: It's a very packed subplot. Some tips: 1) define the figure-window size and paper size before you plot 2) avoid the titles 3) all plots have the same time axis, so just plot xlabes of the last one 4) put the legend inside the plot

Comment: As others have suggested, you have too many plots in one figure. Just to check, try plotting each spectogram in a separate figure, it should display just fine.

Comment: Maybe a logarithmic scale on the y axis might help.

Comment: So The plots were just to big to use, I had to manually assign the plot sizes and locations, Thanks for all your help though!